# Solution Import Error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

[image: Error Message]

Error Text: The Requested Record was not found or you do not have sufficient permissions to view it.

This is occurring because I have need to import a new solution from our UAT environment to our DEV environment.

It looks like two system views are missing.

Comment: Could you please add the text of the error message to your post? If it's only in your pic others will not be able to find this post searching for this error message.

Comment: thats changed now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Views for two tables in SQL had additional attributes. removed unused attributes. now works.